# Why "de" in "J'estime que c'est de sa faute"

Tags: prépositions

An example sentence from a [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/estimer):

> J'estime que c'est de sa faute.

The provided translation is

> I reckon that it's his fault.

Why is *de* necessary in the sentence? It seems that with *de*, the translation would be

> I reckon that it's **of** his fault.

which would not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little difference in french between the two sentences, with or without *de*.

> c'est de sa faute

That is more or less *he is responsable for that* or *that has occured because of him*

> C'est sa faute

It can be a familiar form of *c'est de sa faute*, which if often used by children. Else, it means that a fault has been commited and the fault is his one

IMHO a better translation would be

> I think this happened because of him

Answer (score 0):

*De* is **not** necessary and both are correct :

> C'est de ma faute.
>   C'est ma faute.

[Grevisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Grevisse) says only *C'est ma faute* is mentioned by [Littré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise), and by [Le Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l%27Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) . He adds though that the phrase with *de* is often found in literary language. [Le trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/faute) (II B) gives the *de* form as colloquial.

> ♦ Fam. C'est de ma (ta, sa, etc.) faute. Même sens.

Note that if you name the complement, it is normally introduced by *de*

> C'est de la faute de ma mère.

but Grevisse says that

> C'est de la faute à ma mère.

is more informal.